# What is optical transfer function in Image restoration?

Tags: image, image-processing, filter

I am studying Inverse Filtering, I was trying to code it, I sought out some references from the net. Everyone has considered optical transfer function which is no where to be seen in Gonzalez Book I am referring to.

```
% Inverse_Filter_Demo-


clc
clear all
close all


original_image=imread('cameraman.jpg'); %loading the original (un-blurred) image
original_image=double(original_image);

%The  blur function (PSF- Point Spread Function) that will be added  to the original image
PSF=fspecial('motion',20,45);

%Adding blur to the original image
degraded_image = imfilter(original_image,PSF,'circular','conv');

OTF= psf2otf(PSF,[size(degraded_image,1) size(degraded_image,2)]);%Getting OTF from PSF
Inverse_Filter=conj(OTF)./((abs(OTF)).^2); %The inverse filter

%Preforming Fourier Transform to the degraded image
FT_degraded_image=fftn(degraded_image);

%Preforming the restoration itself
restored_image=abs(ifftn(FT_degraded_image.*Inverse_Filter));

%Presenting the restoration results:

figure;
set(gca,'Fontsize',14);
colormap(gray);
imagesc(original_image,[0 255]);
truesize;    
title('Original image');


figure;
set(gca,'Fontsize',14);
colormap(gray);
imagesc(degraded_image,[0 255]);
truesize;    
title('Degraded image');


 figure;
set(gca,'Fontsize',14);
colormap(gray);
imagesc(restored_image,[0 255]);
truesize;    
title('Restoration of the degraded image (using Inverse Filter)');
```

Answer (score 7):

Your question is unclear, and probably more appropriate for (dsp.stackexchange.com). However, if what you are asking is "what is the optical transfer function?" then the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_transfer_function) for OTFs is a fine place to start.

The simplest way to think about it is that the Optical Transfer Function is the Fourier transform of the point-spreading function (PSF). Usually PSF is a filter (convolution kernel) that describes how a single pin-hole type light source would get smeared into an actual image via some device.

The OTF is just the amplitude/phase representation of that smearing process. It is the filter that the image's Fourier transform would be *multiplied by in phase space* to produce the smeared, true output image's Fourier transform (instead of convolving, which is what you do with the PSF in the spatial domain). Applying the inverse Fourier transform after applying the OTF should give you the actual image the device would produce.

For mathematical convenience, and sometimes for processing efficiency, it can be more expedient to work with the OTF instead of the regular spatial domain's PSF. This is why you'll see some algorithms and textbooks describe their methods with the OTF instead of the PSF.